# Waterline causing 100% CPU Usage

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sails.js, waterline

Can anyone help me with my waterline configuration? I'm using waterline in my application and it's showing 100% CPU usage. This is due to database fetching in the background. Does anyone know how to disable it or reduce this fetching? If anyone has any other solutions, I would be happy to hear them. Thanks

Comment: We can't see your code, and your description is too vague. You're going to have to debug your application and find out why unless you can give more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution somewhere. The problem was with waterline associations. I removed find and populate methods and used query method for native query and it improved performance for around 300%

Comment: Not only was your question vague, but so is this answer!